# Is there any way to create tab based application for Android 2.2 os to Android 4.0 os except TabActivity?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-tabs

I am developing an application in that I need to design tabs. I designed using Action bar but it is not working in Android 2.2 os.

Can anybody tell me how to design my app for Android 2.2 to 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

[ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is the defacto standard for implementing the new Android design patterns that also work on older android versions, while maintaining a single codebase.

It supports Andriod 2.2

I suggest you look at the samples and run them on your Android 2.2 device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can import the library and use it,which supports  in all versions.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Don't forget to give this in manifest.

android:minSdkVersion="8"

android:targetSdkVersion="16"